# Passing ARC closure for Future poll_read gives `error[E0532]: expected unit struct, unit variant or constant, found struct `tokio::io::ReadBuf``

Tags: rust

I want to pass a closure go be executed on the `poll_read` and `poll_write` of a struct:

```
use core::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use hyper::client::connect::{Connection, Connected};
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};
use std::sync::Arc;


pub type OnPollRead = Arc<dyn Fn(&mut Context<'_>, &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> + Send + Sync>;
pub type OnPollWrite = Arc<dyn Fn(&mut Context<'_>, &[u8]) -> Poll<core::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>> + Send + Sync>;


pub struct CustomResponse {
    on_poll_read: Option<OnPollRead>,
    on_poll_write: Option<OnPollWrite>,
}

impl AsyncRead for CustomResponse {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        (self.on_poll_read)(cx.waker().clone(), buf)
    }
}

impl AsyncWrite for CustomResponse {
    fn poll_write(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &[u8]
    ) -> Poll<Result<usize, std::io::Error>> {
        (self.on_poll_write)(cx.waker().clone(), buf)
    }
        fn poll_flush(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>
    ) -> Poll<Result<(), std::io::Error>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }

    fn poll_shutdown(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>
    ) -> Poll<Result<(), std::io::Error>>
    {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let on_poll_read = Arc::new(|&mut Context, &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf| -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    });
    let on_poll_write = Arc::new(|&mut Context, &[u8]| -> Poll<core::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>>{
        Poll::Ready(Ok(0))
    });
}
```

I get these errors:

```
error[E0532]: expected unit struct, unit variant or constant, found struct `tokio::io::ReadBuf`
  --> src/main.rs:47:53
   |
47 |     let on_poll_read = Arc::new(|&mut Context, &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf| -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use struct pattern syntax instead: `tokio::io::ReadBuf { buf, filled, initialized }`
   | 
  ::: /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.2.0/src/io/read_buf.rs:27:1
   |
27 | pub struct ReadBuf<'a> {
   | ---------------------- `tokio::io::ReadBuf` defined here

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn for<'r, 's, 't0> Fn(&'r mut Context<'s>, &'t0 [u8]) -> Poll<std::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>> + Send + Sync` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:50:25
   |
50 |     let on_poll_write = Arc::new(|&mut Context, &[u8]| -> Poll<core::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>>{
   |                         ^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn for<'r, 's, 't0> Fn(&'r mut Context<'s>, &'t0 [u8]) -> Poll<std::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>> + Send + Sync`
   = note: required by `Arc::<T>::new`

error[E0618]: expected function, found enum variant `(self.on_poll_read)`
  --> src/custom_transporter.rs:54:9
   |
54 |         (self.on_poll_read)(cx.waker().clone(), buf)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------------
   |         |
   |         call expression requires function
   |
help: `(self.on_poll_read)` is a unit variant, you need to write it without the parenthesis
   |
54 |         (self.on_poll_read)
   |
```

I tried `help:` (self.on_poll_read) `is a unit variant, you need to write it without the parenthesis`, but without the parenthesis, I get

```
error[E0599]: no method named `on_poll_write` found for struct `Pin<&mut CustomResponse>` in the current scope
```

which is even more strange.

Also, for `expected unit struct, unit variant or constant, found struct`tokio::io::ReadBuf``, I have no idea of what's happening

Here's a playground with the errors: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2dbc27980f9cf738947b8102cdde812

Comment: That's not how you write a closure. *Parameters* go between the `| |`s, not *types*. If you want unused parameters to be annotated with their type, use `_` as a placeholder. [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8542d4f04795951f5fcf34d5e0c115c6)

Comment: @kmdreko thanks, that's rigth. What about the self.on_poll_read call?